# mySQL query in C++

Tags: c++, mysql

In the following code for retrieving data via a SQL query from the db, is there a way I can replace row[0] with fieldname. I am only enclosing the relevant part of the code

```
MYSQL_RES *resptr;
MYSQL_ROW row;

while ( ( row = mysql_fetch_row(resptr)) != NULL ) 
{
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
string key = row[0];
 }
```

row[0] is the trans_date column. the code works fine as it is right now, but is there a way to assign key by using the fieldname vs. having to remember all the field numbers.
thanks!

Comment: You could have an enum to represent columns names. If you do this you should have a test that compare table columns and your enum.

Comment: thanks anno, that's simpler...so if I wrote enum {trans_date, fname, lname}; I could just write string key=row[trans_date]; then I wouldn't need a test, would I?

Comment: By a test, I mean you should have in your test suite a test that checks that you haven't changed your columns order or name. Imagine you change trans_date place to fname, now row[trans_date] will return the wrong value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve field names by doing

```
field = mysql_fetch_field(resptr);
std::cout << field->name;
```

(Put in a while loop to loop through all field)

But you can't call `row[fieldName]`. What you can do though is define variables to map column names and numbers

```
int id = 0;
int trans_date = 1;
// Code happening here
std::cout << row[id] << " " << row[trans_date];
```

**UPDATE:** You could always do something like this (using STL's map):

```
map<string, int> columns;
int i = 0;
while(field = mysql_fetch_field(resptr)){
  columns.insert(pair<string,int>(field->name, i++));
}
```

And then use `row[columns["name"]];`.

Comment: when I have 8 columns, I am basically mapping field names to field numbers so that instead of using field numbers in my code, I use the field names - but it seems like a lot of effort to get that done. isn't there a way to do something like row[i]=field->name..

Comment: thx, that works too. I wonder whether I should go with enum or your solution ;-)

Comment: The advantage of the map solution is that if you change your columns name, the map will return an invalid iterator. Also, changing your column order in your table won't affect you much (if it's done when the application is not running). The enum solution is faster, but that's a Micro-Optimization.

Comment: @Vache, I get an error with columns.insert to the effect of error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>::insert(char*&, int)’....

Comment: I edited it to: columns.insert(pair<string,int>(field->name, i++)); and that fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++) solves this problem. You can say things like:

```
string key = row["key"];
```

or by use of its [SSQLS feature](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/ssqls.html), this:

```
MyTableStructure foo = result[i];
cout << "The key is " << foo.key << endl;
```